# c fgetpos giving wrong position

Tags: c, fopen, fgetpos

I am new to C and I have this code:

```
f = fopen( argv[1], "rb" );
fseek( f, 64, SEEK_SET );
fpos_t pos;
fgetpos (f, &pos);
printf("%x", pos);
```

However, this returns 40, even though it's supposed to be returning 64. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: For one thing, is there actually 64 bytes in the file you're testing this with?

Comment: What is the length of the file you are opening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using %x. It's saying 40 as in 0x40, the hexadecimal number. You need %i or %d to get a decimal number.

Answer (score 4):

You are outputting 64 in hex format, `"%x"`. Since 64=0x40, the mystery is solved!

Answer (score 1):

4 * 16 is 64

Answer (score 1):

whatever you are printing is in hex format. 40 in decimal is 64. `Do you mean the file size is 0x64 or 0x40`

Answer (score 1):

`fpos_t` is not (necessarily) an arithmetic type and cannot be used with `printf`. An implementation could even store it as a structure containing an *encrypted* position if it liked. Use `ftell` (or `ftello` if available) to get the file offset in a meaningful numeric form. `fgetpos` is largely useless.